# How to get the code coverage for the Web App?

Tags: selenium, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm have repo A, where we have our application code and repo B where we have Selenium code. Now we need to get the code coverage.

Any possible solutions?

Comment: Note: here we have one possible way https://dzone.com/articles/verifying-end-to-end-test-code-coverage-using-jaco  but it's not generating report.

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of going down a rat-hole trying to calculate code-coverage from system-tests.  Code coverage, as measured with tools like jacoco, is typically done on unit-tests as part of the source-code build.   That is, it's generated as part of the 'test' or 'integration-test' phase of the same maven build that did the 'compile' phase.  Jacoco is very easy to utilize in this scenario.

Selenium tests are more system-test level in that they work on a running system.  Source code instrumentation on the .CLASS files is more difficult in this realm, so you would have to jump through painful hoops to get jacoco results from selenium.

Further, chasing code-coverage in Selenium is a bad idea.  When you want to insure all branches are covered, you have to write a bunch of tests to test the permutations.  You want a lightweight framework, i.e. unit test, to verify permutations.  Using a heavyweight framework like selenium will mean you are spending a LOT of time spinning up and down containers.  That's not to say Selenium is bad.  You have to do measured-code-coverage in unit-test land, and then demonstrate that those unit tests are meaningful with a handful of system tests.  Selenium (unmeasured) gives credibility that a statement like "we have unit tests with 80% code coverage" indicates "our system has reliable tests"